# Share data between Node server and client

Tags: node.js, express, electron, port

I have wrote an electron app which simutaneously starts client (a react site) and server (nodejs) when the app starts.
The server serves as a pass-through controller as my client cannot make direct API calls due to CORS issue.

However, the server (nodejs express) needs to figure out an open port to use in runtime, how can it communiate back to client that which point it is using?

I've considered let server writing to a file but it is not a good idea, as client code shouldn't access local files.

Another option I've considered is to use local storage, but server cannot write to client local storage either.

Any other recommendations?
Or if sharing is not possible, is there any way to solve the finding open port issue?

Comment: Kindly add minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What do you mean 'client' here?

Comment: My client here is a react app.

Comment: @cherry From node server, you can have CORS header setup to avoid client side CORS issue.
Regarding the port, client should know which port to access which you can decide before hand and configure in your code/config. Or you can bring a webserver in front of your node server. This webserver (nginx) should know which port node server is running and client can directly hit webserver, without worrying about port.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your CORS issue by following express recommendation instead of working around it.

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html